# Where are iCloud documents stored in the file system?

Tags: terminal, icloud, command-line, filesystem, file

Where are iCloud documents stored in the file system?

Under Finder you can find the iCloud directory, however 'Get Info' gives absolutely no clue as to where these files are located in the file system.  So if your in a terminal / commnad-line prompt, its not clear where to find these files.

Its useful to know if your trying to create soft links to files under iCloud OR have scripts that need to access those files.  As opposed to just finding them under Finder.

Answer (score 0):

The following website suggests iCloud documents are stored under:

> ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents

https://www.macworld.com/article/2310807/how-to-access-icloud-files-from-your-mac.html